# What is it called when i want to simulate a system and want to run it many times?

Tags: terminology

So i have this project where i have to simulate a gaming situation. My ideas for how to do this are to do it in Unity, XNA or just textbased in VS without any extra tools. One thing i need is the possibility that it can run the test really fast and i thereby want to find some information about how good the different environments would be at solving this. For that i either need some help finding this information or at the very least a name for what its called when you want to simulate a situation really fast.

Comment: Profiling? Benchmarking? Automated testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you want to **[Stress test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing)** the system.

Checkout this **[article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2028882/keep-it-stable-stupid-how-to-stress-test-your-pc-hardware.html)** that lists various **tools** and describes the **principles** behind stress-testing a PC by simulating a gaming workload (which is exactly what you are looking for).

Comment: Thanks alot this together with some feedback my supervisor gave me gives me a quite clear indication that i should use basic C# for simulating and then use either unity or xna for visualising one "run" of the system.